# DotsPageIndicator don't appear on round screen

Tags: android

I have a smartwatch with round screen. I made a GridViewPager with DotsPageIndicator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />

<android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">
</android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>

</FrameLayout>
```

When gravity of page_indicator is on top the dots appear, but when I change it to the bottom (that's where I want them) they don't appear.

Comment: I'm not into wearable layouts, but I think if you set your GridViewPager's layout_height to match_parent the Indicator is below your screen. What about using a RelativeLayout and align both views with dependencies. (layout_above="@+id/page_indicator" for the Pager and layout_alignParentBottom for the Indicator) ?

Comment: Try putting 
`app:layout_box="all"`
in FrameLayout parameters. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html)